# How would you analyze an Ubuntu server?

Tags: 14.04, 18.04, system, do-release-upgrade

I am assigned with upgrading our Ubuntu 14.04 server to Ubuntu 18.04, what are some system files/configs I should check pre-upgrade and verify post-upgrade. The purpose of the server is produce reports using proprietary software, so I realize that the software should be verified that it can use newer libraries, upgraded packages, etc., but are there any system checks that I should capture and verify afterwards?

How you would upgrade your server?

Currently, I am checking for these items:

- service --status-all
- df -h
- ntpq -pn
- ifconfig -a
- route -n
- service sssd status
- realm list
- crontab -l (root)

I am also familiar that the upgrade path is from 14 to 16 to 18. thanks.

Comment: Man, not even a comment on this. Sheesh.